# Edit an privileged file via bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I need to edit an privileged file using bash on Ubuntu 14.04
This simple command is not working:

```
sudo echo $someText >> $privilegedFile
```

I get this error:

*Permission denied*

I have no idea what is wrong with it.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of `$privilegedFile`?

Comment: There are 2 command `echo` and `>>`, the `sudo` privilege escalation is only applied to `echo`. See chepner's answer below:

Comment: ^^ `>>` is not command.

Answer (score 3):

The shell processes the redirection *before* it runs `sudo`, so `$privilegedFile` is still opened using the current user's permissions.

One workaround is to open the file with a program run by `sudo` rather than using redirections.

```
echo "$someText" | sudo tee -a "$privilegedFile"
```

Another is to start an entirely new shell with `sudo` and execute the full command in that shell.

```
sudo sh -c "echo '$someText' >> '$privilegedFile'"
```

Comment: `sudo sh -c "..."` opens up to injection attacks. To make this safe you'd want to pass values as environment variables and single-quote the code; see my comment on the answer by slon-says-hello.

Comment: I'd love to go back in time and ask this guy why he thought that was an alternative worth mentioning.

Comment: (I suppose with bash 5, `sudo bash -c "echo ${someText@Q} >>${privilegedFile@Q}"` would work safely too).

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
sudo sh -c "echo $text >> $file"
```

Comment: `sudo sh -c "..."` is a source of serious security problems. What if `text='Never run $(rm -rf ~)'`?

Comment: You could avoid that by instead running `sudo text="$text" file="$file" sh -c 'echo "$text" >>"$file"'` -- notice how single-quotes are used so command substitution happens in the child copy of `sh`, not the parent instance.

Answer (score -3):

do

```
sudo chmod u+xrw FILE
```

and

```
sudo nano FILE
```

Don't use echo for editing, try nano, gedit or vi.

Comment: If it fails, type sudo -s, enter password and then try the commands without adding 'sudo'

Comment: Editing a file by appending the output of `echo` is perfectly reasonable in a non-interactive shell.